# Store .txt File in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my full code code to read a file:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <String> words = new ArrayList <String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("3LetterWords.txt"));
        String word;
        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null ){
            words.add(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String [] wordList = new String[words.size()];
    words.toArray(wordList);
    List<String> combinations = display(new ArrayList<>());
}

public static  List<String> display(ArrayList<String> combinations) {
    int counter = 1;
    for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++) {
        for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++) {
            for (char c3 = 'a'; c3 <= 'z'; c3++) {
                String combo = "" + c1 + c2 + c3;                    
                combinations.add(combo);
                System.out.println("" + counter++ + " " + c1 + c2 + c3);
            }
        } 
    }
    return combinations;
}
```

When I run the program, I get an error in the output that I'm not sure how to read or interpret (in NetBeans). I want the `.txt` file to be read, then stored into the `ArrayList`:
The `ArrayList` is created to hold all the information from the file. Use an `ArrayList` so that you don't have to know the size of the file.

The `BufferedReader` commands locate the file and open it for reading.

The `while` loop reads information in line-by-line until it sees the “null” or “end of file” character. It then adds each entry to the `ArrayList`.

The `catch` section makes sure you don't read past the end of the file.

The second `try` section closes the file.

The last function is to convert the `ArrayList` to an array, so that you can search through it.

Added full code:
For context: I need to use a .txt file of 3 letter words for sort/search methods used between both array lists.

ERROR:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 3LetterWords.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    at wordleproj.WordleProj.main(WordleProj.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.BufferedReader.close()" because "br" is null
    at wordleproj.WordleProj.main(WordleProj.java:26)
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/NetBeans/12.6/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/mac/Library/Caches/NetBeans/12.6/executor-snippets/run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting? I also don't understand "convert the ArrayList to an Array, so that you can search through it" — you can search an ArrayList too.

Comment: @Scott Its required of me to use an array for various search methods. How do I include the error? Are you able to copy the code and paste it into java?

Comment: Edit the question and add the error there itself. I tried it locally it worked fine for me though.

Comment: Your Java program cannot find file `3LetterWords.txt`. According to your code, Java will search for that file in the working directory.

Comment: @Abra But the file exists on my laptop. I have that file in the desktop.

Comment: The "desktop" is not the working directory.

Comment: @Abra How would I fix that?

Comment: @creativethoughts You need to copy `3LetterWords.txt` to whatever directory your code is running from. Alternatively, you need to provide an absolute path to the file you're trying to open (e.g. `path/to/desktop/3LetterWords.txt`)

Comment: I Googled for **windows path to desktop**. The following two results seem appropriate for finding the actual path to the _Desktop_ folder. [Get path of the Desktop folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1663587/get-path-of-the-desktop-folder) and [How to get the real path of Desktop in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1489874/how-to-get-the-real-path-of-desktop-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Add the following line to method `main`. It will print out the path to the working directory: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a file `3LetterWords.txt` in your project or add file path.

```java
// you don't have the path but only the filename so the file should be in your project.
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("3LetterWords.txt"));
```

OR specify the path

```java
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\3LetterWords.txt"));
```

Comment: I still dont understand. How would I make my file read by the program?

Comment: you need add file path in code like:
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\3LetterWords.txt"));

Comment: What operating system do you use? maybe it's not in the right path